# Install php 7.X (for new wiki) alongside php 5.3 (for old wiki) on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php, php7, mediawiki

I would like to replace the ancient Mediawiki (version 1.21.2,l PHP version 5.3.3, MySQL 5.1.73) used by my company with a brand new Mediawiki site running the latest version (requires php 7.0.13  or newer) and with brand new content.

Naturally, I'd like to leave the old wiki intact until the new wiki surpasses it. The old wiki is on http://XX.XX.XX.XX:800. I'd like the new wiki to be simultaneously available on http://XX.XX.XX.XX:801.

I've tried to upgrading removing php 5.3 and installing php 7.1 ([from this site](https://webtatic.com/packages/php71/)) but the old wiki was no longer accessible after the install. It appears that the old mediawiki was incompatible with php 7.1, so I had to roll back to php 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever way you choose to get php7 (I like RedHat's Software Collections, but they only offer PHP 7.0 for RH/CentOS 6), the thing you need to have in mind is that you can't have two versions of `mod_php` loaded in your `httpd` at the same time.

While theoretically, you can run an entirely separate httpd for port 801, 
I suggest you install `php-fpm` for PHP7, that way you have a separate daemon that `httpd` `ProxyPass`es or `SetHandler`s its requests to. (Plus, once you are rid of `mod_php`, you can switch from prefork MPM to anything better, like worker MPM.)